# Suppose I schedule a Schedulable batch job and my profile is "API User" and then it upserts

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

Suppose I schedule a Schedulable batch job and my profile is "API User" and then it upserts and a trigger runs to insert/update records. In whose context it will run? Who will show as "last modified by" and can I add a Validation rule that it's only upserted by my profile?

Can i use `NOT($Profile.Name='API User')`.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

The record will show as edited/inserted by the user who was used to schedule the job. So if it's your user that scheduled the job, then your used would show up in the audit fields.

With regards to managing permission, it could be done in any of a number of ways. It depends on the use case really. Are these records that should actually never be edited or created by an end user? Remove Edit/Create permissions for that object at the profile level. Should these records be editable by end users, but a particular fields should not? Make it read only at the profile level. Should this field be editable by end users, but only in a particular context? Use a validation rule, but I would prefer to use a custom permission here instead of a hardcoding the Profile Name.